# Is there a way to know whether active worksheet (C# Excel Introp) has been filled while filling data rows?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I Have been using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to create excel files with huge data  which can't be fit into one worksheet of a excel application so i had to create new worksheets to add data in the rows. 
Is there any API exist to know that excel worksheet has been filled with rows ?

Comment: I don't think so. Is not a matter of API, is a matter data availability, and I don't think worksheets store such information! Anyway, if you are dealing with so much information, why don't you use a database engine?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But as per Excel specifications one worksheet can have 1,048,576 rows and i want my application to be notified when all the rows are filled at runtime so that i can create a new worksheet for rest of the data.

Comment: I misunderstood your question... Doesn't interop raise a exception you can catch?